# Is it possible to return content from a custom window in TinyMCE 4?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Like many others, due to the limitations of TinyMCE's Image Plugin, I've decided to take the route of creating one that ties into my site's own uploading system.

I've gotten this partially working and pulling up a individual page, designed just for the purpose. However, now I want to return content from selecting images on this page. Is that possible or am I hitting a dead end?

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('imageLoader', function(editor, url) {    
    // Adds a menu item to the tools menu

    editor.addButton('imageLoader', {
    icon: 'mce-ico mce-i-link',
    image: 'Photos.png',
    onclick: function() {
      // Open window
      editor.windowManager.open({
        title: 'Image Loader',
        url: 'load_images',
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        onsubmit: function(e) {
          // Insert content when the window form is submitted
          editor.insertContent('Image To Insert');
        }
      });
    }
    });

    return {
        getMetadata: function () {
            return  {
            name: "Image Loader"
            };
        }
    };  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We made this a lot easier in TinyMCE 5 with a new URL dialog api:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/urldialog/

In version 4, I believe the usual technique was to (inside the iframe) access the TinyMCE instance that opened the dialog via `window.parent.tinymce.activeEditor`, and then replicate the onsubmit function there. With the editor instance you can insert whatever content you need to and then `editor.windowManager.close()` will close the topmost window (i.e. the url dialog).

For more advanced use cases, `editor.windowManager.getParams()` can be used to pass information between the plugin and dialog, although perhaps not from the dialog to the plugin. `editor.plugins` is another possible technique, it's a name/value object of active plugin instances (it's a live reference to the return value from the `PluginManager.add` init function which can be mutated at runtime).

These are all fairly complicated, but likely more reliable than searching for the dialog iframe from your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, although this is likely not the most elegant solution.
The image that I'm selecting is passed into a hidden text input in my custom page. From there, on Submit or Closing the TinyMCE 4 Frame, I use this snippet:

```
let getVal = $('[role="application"]').find('iframe')[1].contentWindow.document.getElementById("imgHolder").value;
```

In order:

1. It first finds the iFrame. Since both external pages and the editor itself use iFrames, this will generally be the 'second' iFrame - unfortunately, it isn't given an ID.
2. "contentWindow.document.getElementByID" fetches the hidden input, in my case named "imgHolder"
3. From here, you can get your content as normal with .value, and insert it into the TinyMCE Editor.

I hope this helps point others in the right direction, especially knowing that it gets asked a lot for TinyMCE 4. Further I hope this can be made a bit more elegent as well.